# passing func_pointer to sort()

Tags: c++

Learning passing lamda function pointer to sort().

I created one strange compare function, 3 is larger than anything while other numbers follow the normal comparison rule.

Then i pass the function pointer to sort function that takes in a vector.

I am expecting results to be like 3, 5, 4

but the actual result is like 5, 4, 3.

Will you please help explain a bit what is going on in the background and why my strange function is not affecting the result.

```
int main()
{

    //strange compare function, 3 is larger than anything, whlie other numbers follow normal rule
    auto plarger = [](int a, int b)
    {
        if((a==3) && (b !=3))
        {
            cout<<"i am here"<<endl;
            return true;
        }
        else return a>b;
    };

    vector<int> s { 3, 4, 5 };
    sort(s.begin(), s.end(), plarger);
    for (auto i : s)
    {
        cout << i << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Line numbers make the code annoying to folk out here to toss into an editor and try out if needed. Best to leave them out in the future.

Comment: What if `b` is 3? You have no special case for that.

Comment: Are you sure your comparison function follows [all requirements](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare), including the very important [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings)?

Comment: @tkausl, that is my lack of understanding. It is a vector of integers, which is a and which is b?

Comment: That's almost up to you. I recommend using names like `right` and `left` to tell them apart. Sorry. that should be `left` and `right`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, i read about that. Sorry for the sloppiness. I just quickly hacked a function, and just realized that it violates weak ordering rule like irreflexivity. i only have a==3, return true, when the iterator moves to the next, the current a becomes the latter b, it is subject to normal rule like 4>3, so it is contradicting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not consider the case when `b` is 3. Use this as your compare function.

```
auto plarger = [](int a, int b)
{
  if ((a == 3) && (b != 3))
  {
    return true;
  }
  else if ((b == 3) && (a != 3))
  {
    return false;
  }
  else return a>b;
};
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can go a bit simpler.

Comment: The dude is learning! So lets not complicate him with "smart-ness" mate

Comment: Not going for smart. I think you can ditch at least one of the `&&` cases.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why ,but i see the first time the a ==4 b==3,so your return true never run.
[image]

Comment: yes, i just realized that. a b are the moving two numbers in my vector. Given the position of my 3, it is never becoming b. thanks.